# Woocommerce product attributes to be able to use as links

Tags: wordpress, attributes

We changed from Joomla to Wordpress and imported a lot of data. All the attributes have been imported correctly but I am facing the problem that some of the global attributes are YouTube or Vimeo or links to local download files.

I was wondering if there is a way to utilise the displayed value in

brochure.pdf

to convert it into a button through CSS?

I tried to use https://nicolamustone.blog/2016/03/11/make-product-attributes-linkable/

1. adding it to functions.php
2. adding as a code snippet

but both created a 500 error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not add any further information at this point.

Comment: PS: The code is provided on the page link.